# SQL Server 2005: converting smalldatetime to varchar behaves differently in view and 'normal' query

Tags: sql, sql-server, smalldatetime

I have a view that basically just returns all records from a table, and adds a column 'isodate' which is supposed to be the date in ISO-Format.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_bedarfe]
AS 
   SELECT *,convert(varchar(16),datum,20) As isodat FROM bedarfe
GO
```

The "datum"-field is smalldatetime.
The results of a query on isodat were...'surprising', so to make the point clear, I tried this:

```
select top 10 datum,isodat,convert(varchar(16),datum,20) As isodat2 from v_bedarfe
```

which led to:

[image: Screenshot of result from query]

and that looks very wrong.

So I assume I have wrong expectations or am 'abusing' something here, but I don't see what I could be doing wrong and would appreciate any suggestions how to get back on track here...

Thanks

Michael
*(hope the screenshot will display correctly when posting this, preview doesn't show it)*

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't display correctly

Comment: @Steve, yeah, the screenshot didn't display right, but now it does, seems Andomar fixed it).

@Andomar: Thanks! :)  What did you do to make it show up?

Comment: @MBaas: You were linking to a webpage that contained an image.  I right clicked the image and copied the link (which ended in .PNG) and used that as the image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `*` in views is dangerous.  If the table definition changes, `*` can cause the view to map the columns wrong.  Drop & recreate the view without `*`, and see if that fixes the problem.

P.S. Convert 20 is actually ODBC canonical, `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)`, see the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The last parm in convert is the output format.

20 => yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)

131 => dd/mm/yy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM

see [MS SQL convert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx)